# how to perform action when collision happens in swift? (i'm not using sprite kit)

Tags: swift, uiview, collision, detect

```
 var animator0: UIDynamicAnimator!
var gravity0: UIGravityBehavior!
var collision0: UICollisionBehavior!
```

after adding these I made my view fall but when the collision happens I want an action to be performed, I tried as well writing an if statement in the viewdidappear function : if the y coordinate of the view is at an exact point perform action but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your viewcontroller class conforms to protocol, UICollisionBehaviourDelegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollisionBehaviorDelegate
```

Now,

- make viewcontroller delegate of collision object

  ```
   collision0.collisionDelegate = self
  ```
- Implement following method

  ```
  func collisionBehavior(behavior: UICollisionBehavior!, beganContactForItem item: UIDynamicItem!, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying!, atPoint p: CGPoint) {

   print("Collision Detected- \(identifier)")
   //Perform the action you wanted here.

   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out

Comment: after i typed  collision0.collisionDelegate = self in the viewdidload i ran the app and the app crashed, did i have to do something other than doing these 3 steps? Thanks